# QlikSense choosing amount of listed item

Tags: qliksense

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaIyr.png "Qlik Layout"

So I have this screen and I would like to make it so the user can choose the amount of each selected item. I would also like for the KPI to show 0 if nothing is selected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'll try Measure like this:

```
IF(GetSelectedCount(ProductName)>0,SUM(ListPrice), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The amount of item can be set using input boxes. Problem is input box is per variable so you would have to define input boxes for each product and then make long list... even for that you need input box extension from Qlik Branch. In Qlikview there is functionality to add inputSum function in table which could be perfect in your case but is not implemented in QLikSense. If it is really necessary you can create own extension in Qliksense with html table of all products and form which is updating variables.